# Update Insight Custom field => cannot be cast to java.util.Collection'

Tags: groovy, jira

I have a strange problem. My script is practically finished.

To understand the script : In Insight, I have all our servers object created automatically.

We use a monitoring called Centreon, this monitoring send an email to the service desk mailbox automatically when a error occur and a ticket is created. I want to add the corresponding object to the corresponding server.

The name of the server is present in the summary of the email;

> Example : AFDAOS.xxx.int problem alert

A groovy script check the name of the server, if it found a correspond name (in the FQDN Attribute), the object is affected to the ticket.

All code working until the updating of the ticket, i have a statement where all objects are checked, when i found the good object (string currentobject), i want to update the current issue with this object i have the error :

> GroovyInsightException: com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectBean cannot be cast to java.util.Collection'

BUT if I replace currentobject by Objects (I suppose it's an array), the ticket is updating with all objects without any error. I understand that I can only update the ticket with an array and not a unique value... I don't found the good way to do it... Thank you for your help.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.CommentBean;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.channel.external.api.facade.ObjectFacade
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectAttributeBean
import com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectBean
import groovy.transform.ToString

Class objectFacadeClass = ComponentAccessor.getPluginAccessor().getClassLoader().findClass("com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.channel.external.api.facade.ObjectFacade");
def objectFacade = ComponentAccessor.getOSGiComponentInstanceOfType(objectFacadeClass);

//CustomField jiraCustomField = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(12124);

CustomField insightCF = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager().getCustomFieldObject(12124);


Class iqlFacadeClass = ComponentAccessor.getPluginAccessor().getClassLoader().findClass("com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.channel.external.api.facade.IQLFacade");
def iqlFacade = ComponentAccessor.getOSGiComponentInstanceOfType(iqlFacadeClass);

def objects = iqlFacade.findObjectsByIQLAndSchema(10,"objectTypeId = 2443");
//def test = "AF-172738"
//def ObjectInsightBean = objectFacade.loadObjectBean(test)
//log.warn("ObjectInsightBean " + ObjectInsightBean)
def n = 0
(objects).each {
CurrentObject = objects[n]
def fqdnvalue = objectFacade.loadObjectAttributeBean(CurrentObject.getId(),47464).getObjectAttributeValueBeans()[0]; //Load Attribute Value



def fqdn_string = fqdnvalue.toString()
def fqdn_string_split = fqdn_string.split("\\(");
def fqdn_string_split_1 = fqdn_string_split[1]
def fqdn_string_split_2 = fqdn_string_split_1.substring(0, fqdn_string_split_1.length() - 2);

result = (issue.getSummary().contains(fqdn_string_split_2)) // if the value fqdn_string_split_2 present in the summary => result = true
if (result==true){
log.info("Statement " + "True" + CurrentObject);
MutableIssue mi = (MutableIssue) issue;
mi.setCustomFieldValue(insightCF, CurrentObject); // => Work if i replace CurrentObject by objects
ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().updateIssue(currentUser, mi, EventDispatchOption.DO_NOT_DISPATCH, false); // Error GroovyInsightException: com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectBean cannot be cast to java.util.Collection'

}
log.info("fqdn_string_split_2 " + fqdn_string_split_2)
log.info("Result " + result)
n ++
return result;
}
```

Solved by converting the string into List:

```
if (result==true){
    //log.info("Statement " + "True" + CurrentObject);
    MutableIssue mi = (MutableIssue) issue;
    def CurrentObject_list = [CurrentObject];
    log.info("List " + CurrentObject_list);
    mi.setCustomFieldValue(insightCF, CurrentObject_list); // => Work if i replace CurrentObject by objects
    ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().updateIssue(currentUser, mi, EventDispatchOption.DO_NOT_DISPATCH, false); // Error  GroovyInsightException: com.riadalabs.jira.plugins.insight.services.model.ObjectBean cannot be cast to java.util.Collection'
    
    }
//log.info("fqdn_string_split_2 " + fqdn_string_split_2)
//log.info("Result " + result)
n ++
return result;
```

Comment: I really fail to understand this way of writing: `def n = 0
(objects).each {
CurrentObject = objects[n]`

Comment: `replace currentobject by Objects` what is `Objects`?

Comment: I solved my problem by using: def CurrentObject_list = [CurrentObject];

Objects get all object from Insight Plugin from Insight add on (list of all servers).